# Scaling images for retina canvas

Tags: iphone, canvas, createjs

I'm in the process of building a game for iPhone (retina)

My plan is to set up my canvas at the largest screen size 414 x 736 (iPhone 6 plus) create my images 3x the size and scale all down (scale = 0.33) because iPhone 6 is 3x the size

The other screen sizes for iPhone6 and 5 have the same aspect ratio, so this size (414 x 736) will be scaled to other sizes easily.

Does the canvas still have to be scaled, can I not simply keep one size and scale down all images?

Hope someone has had experience of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better results, you should provide your application with @1x, @2x and @3x assets.
Additionally, once Apple will turn on App Slicing, only the assets with the good size for the user's device will be downloaded from the app store, allowing smaller storage impact for your app.

@1x is the size in pixel that matches Interface Builder's "points" size system.

You can use a tool (like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/asset-catalog-creator-app/id809625456?mt=12)) to create all your assets at the good size automatically. It will save you a lot of time.